# How to get the Default values of a Tkinter Label

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to set the Background Color of Label (which I before changed) back to its default value. How do I get the default values?

My first approach was, after I saw in the Tkinter docs that if u call .configure without passing any arguments, that u get back a dictionary of the contents, was this

```
print label1.configure()[bg]
```

This didnt work for me.

Sorry I am really new and I know its kind of basic question but my web searches just brought me to "How do I change the Background color" etc.

Best regards a beginner in needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the cget method.

```
print label1.cget('bg')
```

Comment: Thanks sorry for not finding it myself